# How effectively did Romans rotate/relieve lines with the cohort system?

Tags: military, ancient-rome, battle, infantry

There is [a similar question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/87e8hj/how_did_romans_rotaterelieve_lines_with_the/) and the original poster of the question uses [a YouTube video to demonstrate the point](https://youtu.be/fDTmgHCVWgg?t=20m21s). That video showcases a rotation of Roman infantry in a cohort.

According to the answers on Reddit, there were rotations of exhausted and fresh troops when gaps among friendly cohorts appears themselves in the frontline, or so it suggests in the answers.

My question is even if descriptions exist in text about the rotation, how effective was that system on the battlefield and at the frontline? Those answers on reddit suggested that the rotation existed. I was however asking the effectiveness of the rotation if it existed. Roman legionaries were very successful but did that success involved the rotation?

My imagination would suggest that the Roman cohorts would hold the enemy in combat and cavalry attack on the flanks... a variation of the hammer and anvil tactic.

Comment: If you're asking how effective it was: very. It was likely a key to the long success off Roman legions recruited in Italy. If you're asking how it was performed: nobody knows. Historians have been arguing about it for centuries, but there is no (known) contemporary description of the mechanism.

Comment: Peter, those answers on reddit suggested that the rotation existed. I was however asking the effectiveness of the rotation if it existed. Roman legionaries were very successful but did that success involved the rotation?

Comment: Read Caesar. There are numerous mentions  of the practice in Gallic Wars, though no description of method.